# Dojo Request won't work properly

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a **div** Tag which has a OnClick Event which triggers a dojo XHR Request.

My Problem is that it will not go into the **.then(lang.hitch(...))** part except if I use break points in **firebug**

```
createTS : function(){
        var container = document.createElement("div");
        console.log("Hallo World");
        xhr("getoptions.php?database=cb_content.sqlite&order=read").then(lang.hitch(this,function(result){console.og("test");this.temp = result.toString().split(";");}));
        var container = document.createElement("div");
        for(var i = 0; i< this.temp.length; i++){
                var span = document.createElement("span");
                span.setAttribute("id",this.temp[i]);
                span.innerHTML = this.temp[i];
                //on(dom.byId(this.temp[i]),"click",this.foo(span.innerHTML));
                span.setAttribute("class","apus_span_item");
                span.setAttribute("onclick","fptr('"+span.innerHTML+"');");
                container.appendChild(span);
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));                            
        }
        console.log("row before return");
        return '<div>'+container.innerHTML+'</div>';
        //return this.templateString2

    },
```

The console tells me "Hallo World" and then it tells me that a GET Request is made and then console tells me "row before return". But the "test" won't be written.

When I make break points it will tell me test.

Anyone has the answer why it won't go into the .then?

Greetings

Comment: could you change: `.then(lang.hitch(this,func..` to `.then(result){lang.hitch(this,func.. }`?

Comment: if that is a copy paste, check out your console.og(...);, also yor code wont work as is, all the creation code should be inside the hitched function, as request is async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except the fact that your code has errors like `console.og()` in stead of `console.log()`, your setup will never work.

You're trying to use a value that is set by an asynchronous request (that's what the XHR request is) inside synchronous code (`this.temp`).

So, it's very likely that the code to create your HTML (the `for` loop) is being executed **BEFORE** the XHR request has completed, and thus, before `this.temp` has been initialized.
The reason that it works when using breakpoints is because you're delaying the HTML creation code until the XHR is completed (because you set a breakpoint).

There are two solutions here. The first one is by converting your XHR request to a synchronous request by setting the `sync` option to `true`. For more information look at the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/xhr.html) or the [API documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojo/request/xhr#1_9dojo_request_xhr___Options_sync).

Another solution would be to make sure the code that creates your HTML is only being executed when the asynchronous request has been completed. You can do that by moving all your code that depends on `this._temp` inside the callback (the function inside the `then()` part).

However, if you need to return something from your callback, you will have to use [deferreds](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/Deferred.html).